# Configure a Create-React-Native-App project to use MobX and use Babel to enable decorators

Tags: react-native, babeljs, mobx

I've created a project with CRNA and after some considerations I've decided to go with MobX for state management. MobX works best with the decorator syntax (most MobX documentation is written using the decorator syntax) so I wanted to install the Babel plugin enabling the use of decorators.

I've successfully installed MobX (`yarn add mobx mobx-react`), but after installing the Babel plugin to enable decorators (`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators` and adding `"transform-decorators"` to the plugins section in `.babelrc`, `yarn start` stopped working throwing an error about react-native-scripts not being found.

I've then run `yarn install`and this time it threw an error saying

```
Error starting packager: TypeError: Invalid Version: undefined
    at new SemVer (D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\semver\semver.js:279:11)
    at Function.major (D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\semver\semver.js:551:10)
    at D:\xdl\src\project\Doctor.js:634:18
    at D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4944:15
    at baseForOwn (D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3001:24)
    at D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4913:18
    at Function.forEach (D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9359:14)
    at D:\xdl\src\project\Doctor.js:624:9
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (D:\Projects\ReactNativePlayground\omar\MRKT\node_modules\xdl\build\project\Doctor.js:615:191)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Does anyone have experience with CRNA and MobX? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it. Turns out that running `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators` broke something. What I should have been running is `yarn add --dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` and add `"transform-decorators-legacy"` to `.babelrc` plugins section. After doing those steps I ran `yarn install` and it fixed my project.

Additionally, my editor (VSCode) threw warnings about extensions being experimental so I added a `jsconfig.json` file to the root folder and added the following inside:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [".expo/*", "node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: Yes. In my specific case using `yarn` instead of `npm` solved my problem.